# Gigya share bar facebook-like button custom title and description

Tags: facebook, gigya

I am using following example from gigya site on my site

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var act = new gigya.socialize.UserAction();
act.setUserMessage("This is the user message");
act.setTitle("Seasons");
act.setLinkBack("https://platform.gigya.com");
act.setDescription("Seasons is a surreal motion graphics animation based on the changing seasons.");
act.addActionLink("Watch this movie", "http://vimeo.com/24496773");
act.addMediaItem({ type: 'image', src: 'http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/160/564/160564685_100.jpg', href: 'http://vimeo.com/24496773' });
var showShareBarUI_params=
{ 
    containerID: 'componentDiv',
    shareButtons: 'facebook-like, Twitter-tweet, googleplus-share, share',
    userAction: act
}
</script>
<div id="componentDiv"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   gigya.socialize.showShareBarUI(showShareBarUI_params);
</script>
```

But when I click on facebook-like button instead of custom title ("Seasons"), and custom description ("Seasons is a surreal motion graphics animation based on the changing seasons."), I am getting title and description from set link

```
act.setLinkBack("https://platform.gigya.com");
```

How can I set my custom title and custom description on facebook-like button.

Thanks